# Edge noframemerging alternatives

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, ie8-compatibility-mode

to Use EDGE shortcut to always launch a page in new session,
For this purpose on IE11 i used -noframemerging flag.
Edge doesn't support “noframemerging” feature.
Trying with -inprivate I get a session dedicated to private instance.
but each private instance shares the same session ID.
is there a flag for EDGE to obtain a different session id for each instance opened from a shortcut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official doc, if you want to use no-merge functionality in Edge, you can use one of the following solutions:

1. Use Profiles in Microsoft Edge - Each profile maps to a different IE session for IE mode pages, so it behaves identically to the no-merge option.
2. Use the `--user-data-dir=<path>` command line, but with a different path for each session. If needed, you can create a utility for the user to run that launches Microsoft Edge and changes the path for the session.

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-faq#does-ie-mode-on-microsoft-edge-support-the-no-merge-option-that-was-supported-in-internet-explorer-11